# Defining abilities via attributes from a polymorphic association in CanCan

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, cancan, polymorphic-associations

I have the following models:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :responses, as: :responseable, dependent: :destroy
end

class Call < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :responses, as: :responseable, dependent: :destroy
end

class Meeting < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :responses, as: :responseable, dependent: :destroy
end

class Response < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :responseable, polymorphic: true # Tested
end
```

In CanCan I am trying to define the abilities on a specific custom Responses action via attributes in the polymorphic association. The action looks like this:

```
class ResponsesController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :authenticate_user!
  load_and_authorize_resource

  respond_to :html, :xml, :js, :json, :pdf


  # GET /responses/polling
  # GET /responses/polling.json
  def polling
    responseable_type = params[:responseable_type]
    klass = [Post, Call, Meeting].detect { |c| responseable_type}
    @responseable = klass.find(params[:responseable_id])
    @responses = @responseable.responses.where("created_at > ?", Time.at(params[:after]))
  end
...
```

And my abilities file looks like this:

```
...
can :polling, Response, :responseable_type = "Post", :responseable => { :user_expert_private => false, :countries => { :id => user.country_ids} }
...
```

This action is run via a javascript function that polls for new responses every 5 seconds. However, when this runs I get the following errors in the log:

```
A NameError occurred in responses#polling:

  uninitialized constant Responseable
  activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:230:in `block in constantize'
```

Any idea the right way to define abilities on attributes from a polymorphic relationship?

Basically, I don't want users to be able to view/create a response unless they `can? show:` the parent object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [wiki article](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Nested-Resources).  There's a section on polymorphic types.  You need to use nested authorization.  Here's the relevant section:

> Let's say tasks can either be assigned to a Project or an Event
>   through a polymorphic association. An array can be passed into the
>   :through option and it will use the first one it finds.

```
load_resource :project
load_resource :event
load_and_authorize_resource :task, :through => [:project, :event]
```

> Here it will check both the @project and @event variables and fetch
>   the task through whichever one exists. Note that this is only loading
>   the parent model, if you want to authorize the parent you will need to
>   do it through a before_filter because there is special logic involved.

```
before_filter :authorize_parent
private
def authorize_parent
  authorize! :read, (@event || @project)
end
```